# how include(mpdf.php)

Tags: php, sql, yii

I am new to yii . Error occured in my controller of actionIndex fuction that is -"include(mpdf.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory. "
   what I can do for solve this problem. Give me guidance about that.
Thank you....

Comment: use this version for yii2: https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-mpdf

Comment: Maybe here : stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory/36577021#36577021